# Flex 3: Key press combination to trigger an event/function

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, keyboard, keypress, combinations

Within a specific canvas, I would like a user to be able to press a combination of keys which will trigger an event.(a bit like a cheat in an old megadrive game). Not sure where to start though. Anyone know if it is possible and if so could you give me a clue with how to start?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* add an eventListener to the top level application for the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` event and check for key combinations there. From [this article](http://flexcomps.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/captur/):

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
 layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
 <mx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
    private function init():void{
     this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
     this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressed);
    }
    private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
      stage.focus = this;
    }
    private function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
       if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 65)
             trace("CTRL A is pressed");
       if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 66)
             trace("CTRL B is pressed");
   }
 ]]>
 </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll be able to have a good stab at it from here. Thanks for the link as well.

Comment: This is true; however as I stated in my own answer, something still needs to dispatch the keyboard event; and I containers do not do so.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com That's true. I'm just not a fan of putting the focus in hidden components just for the sake of dispatching the KEY_UP or KEY_DOWN events. Anything that takes the control of the cursor or focus out of the user's control or relies on the focus in some arbitrary hidden control is not good design in my opinion.

Comment: No argument there.  I didn't notice you were referencing the stage directly.  I had no idea the stage would dispatch the keyboard events [it just came up in another question].  I would have expected the Application to be a child of the stage, though, not the other way around.  Do you have to listen directly to the stage, or can you listen at the application level; as you do here?

Answer (score 2):

A canvas won't dispatch key up or key down events.  You can add a listener to them; as the key events will bubble; but it won't dispatch them alone.  Unfortunately, an input component, such as a textInput, needs to have focus for the key press events to dispatch.

Instead of using a canvas, group, or other container, I'd look into using a [Spark TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextInput.html) with a customized skin that makes it, and the typed text, essentially invisible.

Comment: The only problem with that is that i'm using flex3 which doesn't support spark components. Thanks for the advice anyway!

Comment: @Michael Wilson You can style a MX TextInput to do the same thing, I just perceive it will be harde to do so.