# problem capturing keyboard input for Sprite

Tags: flash, apache-flex, addeventlistener

I an trying to capture keyboard and mouse events for square area on my UI, represented by Sprite. The mouse capture works, the keyboard capture doesn't work at all:

```
private var square:Sprite = new Sprite();
square.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1024, 720);
square.graphics.endFill(); 
square.buttonMode = true; 
...
square.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,reportKeyDown);

private function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
trace("==>reportKeyDown: " + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) + " (key code: " + 
event.keyCode + " character code: " +         event.charCode + ")");
}
```

I never see reportKeyDown executed, even though Sprite object has a focus.
Any idea what the problem is?
Thanks,
-V

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution I suggestion? If it helped, you can upvote it by clicking on the ^ arrow next to my answer. If it helped solve your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6202633/275643) very recently. As Flextras mentioned, controls that don't normally accept keyboard input won't dispatch the keyboard events.

As J_A_X mentioned, you *can* add an eventListener to the top level application for the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` event and check for key combinations there however. From [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6202633/275643):

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
 layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
 <mx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
    private function init():void{
     this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
     this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressed);
    }
    private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
      stage.focus = this;
    }
    private function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
       if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 65)
             trace("CTRL A is pressed");
       if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 66)
             trace("CTRL B is pressed");
   }
 ]]>
 </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard events are only dispatched from controls that accept user input, such a a TextInput.  This is a bit confusing in the docs; because the events are listed on most Flex components.  Your approach looks right, you just need something inside the Sprite that will dispatch those keyboard events.

Comment: Or just listen on the stage: `square.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, ...);`

Comment: @J_A_X IF I understand what you're saying, the Stage will dispatch the keyboard events, is that correct? I had no idea; that seems like a superior approach.

Comment: Stage will *always* dispatch keyboard events so long as the Flash (or Air) app is in focus :)